# IIf(<condition>,<value>,ElseIf<condition>,<value>,<value>) expression is invalid

Tags: sql, ms-access

According to Access, my expression is invalid. This is my expression:

```
Expr1: IIf([POSCOD_0]=[Hot Zip],"Hot",ElseIf[POSCOD_0]=[Warm Zip], "Warm", "Other")
```

Essentially, pseudo code here:

If POSCOD_0 = Hot Zip, then use "Hot", elseif POSCOD_0 = "Warm Zip" use "Warm", else "Other".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot nest `ElseIf` inside of a `IIf`.  But you can nest another `IIf` like so:

```
IIf(POSCOD_0 = [Hot Zip], "Hot", IIf(POSCOD_0 = [Warm Zip], "Warm", "Other"))
```